# Ruby- date manipulation to fetch data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a requirement in ruby where I want to fetch all the data present in database for the current month. However, there is a catch.
I wanted to fetch the data of current month based on plan start data.

```
Ex:
 1. My plan is started on 5th Oct 2022.
 2. Let say, today's date is 3rd Dec 2022. I would want to fetch records from 5th Nov to 3rd Dec.
 3. Let say, today's date is 15th Dec 2022. I would like to fetch records of current cycle that is from 5th Dec till today.
```

There could be many cases, but the idea is I want to fetch the current month records based on the cycle start date for current month.

Since I am new to ruby, can someone please suggest me how to do it using DateTime or any relevant methods. Any help would be appreciated.

model:

```
class Customer
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  include SimpleEnum::Mongoid

  field :topic, type: String # This field is to store title/topic
  field :external_uuid, type: String # This represents unique ID
  field :start_time, type: DateTime
  field :duration, type: Integer
  field :created_at, type: DateTime 

  field :random, type: Float, default: -> { rand.round(8) }

  as_enum :type,
          internal: 'internal',
          external: 'external' 
end
```

Comment: I don't yet understand all the requirements fully. My guess is: The "plan" always starts at the 5th. And you basically need  information from "the  last 5th up to today"? 
How is your data structured? Is there a `plan_start_date` column, or similar? So you basically need the date range to pass to `active_record`?

Comment: Please provide an example of your models, schema, the data and the expected result. That removes any potential ambigiuty around what you actually expect the result to be and actually makes the question answerable.

Comment: Thats not an actual example - its just more useless fluff. Provide an example of the existing data and which rows you expect to be in the result. A good way to do this is with a simple ASCII table. You also haven't provided models, the schema or anything else.

Comment: sorry it was typo. I will provide an example here.

Comment: Monthly recurring plan start at : 5th oct 2022 and records added from 5th oct to 4th Nov, from 5th Nov to 4th Dec and from 5th Dec till today.

Now I want to query the data to get how many records are inserted at any point of time for the same month. 
So If I query for current month, i should get data from 5th Dec till today.
If I query for last month and let say date was 28 Nov as current date, I should get data from 5th Nov to 28Nov.

My model has created_at field present. which has Date format as 'created_at: 2022-12-12 07:26:57.286 UTC'.

Hope this help to explain the usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding that the plan starts on each 5th and you want to have the time-span from  `plan_start` to `NOW`, you can get the start date with something along the lines of

```
require 'date'

plan_start_day = 5
today = DateTime.now.to_date
puts "Today is #{today}"
puts "Today is day #{today.day} of the month, plan starts on #{plan_start_day}."

start =
    if today.day < plan_start_day 
         DateTime.new(today.year,today.month - 1,plan_start_day)
    else 
         DateTime.new(today.year,today.month,plan_start_day)
    end
puts "Applicable plan start is #{start.to_date}"
```

For today we get an output like

```
Today is 2022-12-13
Today is day 13 of the month, plan starts on 5.
Applicable plan start is 2022-12-05
```

Now, assuming that the date you are looking for is in `start_time` column, that is of type `DateTime`, you can just query:

```
Customer.where('start_time > ? AND start_time < ?', start, today.end_of_day)
```

Of course `created_at` would also work, given that this column provides the information needed... Availability of `end_of_day` depends on [Rails version](https://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/end_of_day) but a manual increase as above should be easy enough...

If you want to have the number of items only use

```
Customer.where('start_time > ? AND start_time < ?', start, today.end_of_day).count
```

Now, I'd add this to the `Customer` model class as a static method

```
def self.monthly_sum(date)
    month = (date.day < Customer::PLAN_START_DAY) : date.month - 1 ? date.month 
    plan_start = DateTime.new(date.year, month, Customer::PLAN_START_DAY)
    plan_end = DateTime.new(date.year, month+1, Customer::PLAN_START_DAY)
    Customer.where('start_time > ? AND start_time < ?', plan_start, plan_end).count
end
```

This method uses the assumption that there are no "future" events, thus it would fetch the full month for any date. If the plan_month has already ended, it will get the full data. If it is the current plan_month, we get all data until today (as no newer entries exist).

The `Customer::PLAN_START_DAY` here is a constant.
If the plan start is individual (per user, type, project, ...), you need to get it from the appropriate record and extract the day with the `#day` method presented above.

you can now do

```
Customer.monthly_sum(DateTime.now)
```

or what ever date is applicable and get the number of records matched.

Comment: Yes my model has created_at, and i can use the logic which you shared.
One query, does it also work with the DateTime field. Since the created_at is DateTime field.

Comment: As said, that should just work, yes. ;) ('should' since, as I cannot realy reproduce your issue without the information requested in the comments above.)

Comment: Added the model structure as well.

Comment: Edited the answer based on your last results.